# Is it possible to add more files in an already uploaded IPFS folder?

Tags: nft, ipfs

I have an already uploaded folder of JSON files on IPFS , [HERE](https://lime-spotty-cephalopod-876.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmYLwrqMmzC3k4eZu7qJ4MZJ4SNYMgqbRJFLkyiPtUBZUP/)

My question is can I add more files to this folder? It doesn't seem possible to use Pinata for this but is there any other method to do that?

The reason for doing this is to add new token URIs in a smart contract without uploading new CIDs, so that we don't need to manually update the URIs, instead, the base URI substitution method works for every new token ID being minted.

Comment: don't think that's possible.